# Toggle A-Frame's vr-mode-ui dynamically

Tags: javascript, html5-video, aframe

I am trying to hide/show the A-Frame's `vr-mode-ui` dynamically based on some rules in my code. Initally the `<a-scene>` looks like this:

```
<a-scene id="vr-scene" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
```

In my controller, I am trying to enable and disable it based on a flag:

```
let scene = document.querySelector('#vr-scene');
if (showVR) {
  scene.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled: true');
} else {
scene.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled: false');
}
```

But the moment this toggle happens, I get a error on console which reads like this: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null`

Please advise what's going wrong here. Is there a better way to enable/disable the VR button ?

Here's a simple codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdZWdz

Steps:

1. Click Enable
2. Click Disable
3. Click Enable (VR button doesn't come up)

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to disable it when it's already disabled?

Comment: There are 2 problems here, the `scene.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled: true');` is not bringing back the vr-button. So, the next time it goes in `else` it is still disabled and hence the error. Any ideas why the `enabled` part doesn't bring it back!

Comment: @ngokevin: I have added a codepen to demonstrate the issue I am running into. Please have a look at it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the component doesn't support enabling/disabling much of the button. More of a one-time thing. This can be fixed but will file an issue.

In the meantime, it would be easier to simply toggle the visibility of the button using CSS:

```
document.querySelector('.a-enter-vr-button').style.visible = 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. One of my colleagues helped me figure out that this is a bug and he in fact gave me the same solution as yours.